Vue3 Transitions: Control slide-fade in and slide-fade out independently of each other
I am trying to implement a comment section in my project. Each comment has its own quill editor to answer. The reason behind this on my mobile version I want to display the quill editor fixed to the bottom and on my desktop version I want to display a quill editor right below the comment which the user wants to answer.
However, I am facing one problem with my transition. When you press the comment answer button, you can see how the quill editor pops up from the bottom. When you press anywhere on the screen (except another comment answer button), the editor slides and fades out again.
However, when I press another comment answer button, you can already see the problem. One editor slides and fades out, and the editor of the comment where you pressed the comment answer button slides and fades in. This is what I am trying to solve here.
I need to control the slide-fade in and slide-fade out independently of each other in order to have no slide-fade out animation for the present editor and no slide-fade in animation for the editor of the comment where I pressed the answer button.
When the user clicks somewhere else, the animation should be as usual.
Here is a working example: click!
I appreciate any kind of help!
Kind regards

Since you're willing to make a conditional transition based on a condition with the JS hooks so that way you could double-check if you should do a transition when the editor is already open at the bottom of the page.
Or, you could have something like
<transition :name="transitionName === 'slide-fade'">

with transitionName being a computed checking if the editor is open.
When it is open, set it to false, otherwise set it to 'slide-fade'. This is a quick and easy way to short-circuit your CSS and disable any kind of animation for that specific moment.
Otherwise, maybe you could check on having a higher-up <transition-group> wrapping your iterative v-for that would trigger under specific conditions. What I'm saying is that you could de-correlate your util-quills from the editor from the bottom. Those 2 can be totally independent but react still without the need for a constant v-if of the editor.
You could also store the answers into a Pinia object somewhere, then submit the whole payload to the backend. You per-se don't need to have several instances of the editor with their own text, you can write in it, dump it into the object when closing the current editor and moving to the other question etc. I know that this solution might require quite more modifications but it might be a decent approach overall (sorry if it's not the way you wanted your question to be solved haha).

Can you give me example solving this problem using <transition-group> ?

@Jan not directly, requires quite some code change but the idea would be to control the transitions of the editor mostly.
